# Could not drop NaN values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop NaN values using the dropna() method, provided by Panda. I've read the document and looked at other StackOverflow posts, but I still could not fix the error.

For my code, I will first read an excel file. If the rows have value “-“, I will change it to a NaN value. After that, I will use the method dropna() to drop the NaN values. I will then reassign the result of the dropna() method to a new variable called mydf2. Below are my codes and screenshots

```
mydf = pd.read_excel('pandas lab datasets/singstats_maritalstatus.xlsx', 
na_values='-')

mydf = mydf.set_index(['Variables'])

print(mydf.head(5)) # Original data

mydf2 = mydf.dropna()
print(mydf2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dropna() has worked correctly. You have two print statements. The first one has printed five rows as asked for by `print(mydf.head(5))`.

The output of your second print statement `print(mydf2)` is an empty dataframe [0 rows and 37 columns] because you have apparently got an NaN in each and every row. (see the bottom of your screenshot)

Comment: If your intent was to drop columns that contain NaN values, then the statement should be mydf2 = mydf.dropna(axis=1), because the default is axis=0 which drops rows.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like here that `NaN` is a string, so do:

```
mydf2 = mydf.replace('-',np.nan).dropna()
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code but it still does not work. I went to check the data type of each column using mydf.dtypes. I realise that the columns with NaN values are actually float64. What should I do?

Comment: @Issaki You're sure `mydf2 = mydf.dropna()` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I have double checked my code and it still did not work

Comment: @Issaki Does my code work when you change this line: `mydf = pd.read_excel('pandas lab datasets/singstats_maritalstatus.xlsx', 
na_values='-')` to `mydf = pd.read_excel('pandas lab datasets/singstats_maritalstatus.xlsx')`?

Comment: It doesn't work. Because the value '-' is not registered as an NaN value

Comment: @Issaki Doing that then use my code?

Comment: @Issaki I edited my code.

Comment: dropna() still returns an empty dataframe

Comment: @Issaki WIth my new edited code?

Comment: I used the following code above: mydf2 = mydf.replace('-',np.nan).dropna()

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a piece of code here, it works fine with my data, so try this out.

```
mydf = pd.read_excel('pandas lab datasets/singstats_maritalstatus.xlsx')
to_del = []
for i in range(mydf.shape[0]):
    if "-" in list(mydf.iloc[i]):
        to_del.append(i)
        out_df = mydf.drop(to_del, axis=0)
```

Comment: But my goal is to drop all the rows that have the value "-". So i have to use na_values='-' to convert '-' to NaN value. From there, I will then use dropna().

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted your data, I'm not sure if every row has NaN values or not. If this is so, df.dropna() will simply drop every row. For example, the columns 1981 and 1982 are all NaN values in your image. use `df.dropna(axis=1)` will drop these two columns, and will not return you an empty df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variables':['Total','Single','Married','Widowed','Divorced/Separated'],
                   '1980':range(5),
                   '1981':[np.nan]*5})
df.set_index('Variables')
df.dropna(axis=1)
```